# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString unreliable behavior with Uri containing the colon (:) char in segment name

Tags: c#, .net, url

I get the following results:

```
//Both return True.
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://contoso.com/seg1/2013.05.29_14:33:41", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("seg1/2013.05.29_14:33:41", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

//Both return False.
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("2013.05.29_14:33:41", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("2013.05.29_14:33:41", UriKind.Relative);
```

The problem arose when I needed to construct relative URLs from third-party provided absolute URLs.
Trial and error showed that this happens if there is a colon (:) char in the first segment name.

Is there another way from `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` to check a string as being good in terms of all the segments in order to avoid such a mess?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx) states "Beginning with .NET 4.5, relative URIs with a colon (':') in their first segment are not considered well-formed."

Comment: @JeroenHeier I did get an explanation on the reasons in my MS Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788841/net-4-5-system-uri-iswellformeduristring-method-returns-false-for-relative-uris-with-a-colon-char-in-first-segment. They seem to update the MSDN article after answering me. Even the datetime in the example is the same. But this still leaves the question open. What's the best way to check the incoming URLs?

Comment: If you really want to deviate you could write and document your own method that could use Uri.IsWellFormedUriString and then use some extra checks if that method returns false and segment count is 1.